# Prevent my program from accessing the filesystem

Tags: security, chroot

I have a program that may be compromised, but needs root rights initially. Currently, the program [chroots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into a preconfigured directory and then drops the privileges.

However, I would like to prevent my program from accessing the filesystem at all after it has dropped the root privileges, and if possible not require any configuration. Is there a better way than [creating a temporary directory](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp) in /tmp and chrooting into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up chrooting into a temporary directory (in my case, `/var/run/programname`) and dropping privileges thereafter. This offers adequate protection, and does not require any complicated installation. On the downside, it requires my program to be running as superuser in the first place.

Comment: You can setcap the program with cap_sys-chroot an then you dont need to start as the root user. Just be sure to drop the privilage after the chroot.  libcap-ng makes this easy.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two options:

- Use a security module, such as SELinux, to lock that process out from the rest of the system

This is the proper way to do it, but requires you learn the framework and do a lot of configuration. You can basically set the policy so that this process, or the user running it (or both), can't have any access to the rest of the system.

- Hijack the kernel's filesystem calls to deny them for the user running the compromised program

This is a far less elegant solution, and may have more performance impact, but requires very little configuration, just a little coding. I do something similar in a security module I wrote:

https://github.com/cormander/tpe-lkm

It hooks into execve, mmap, mprotect, and other things. The same could be done for open, write, etc, and deny the system calls based on uid or gid, or even process name.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these options require vastly more configuration than simply chrooting into an empty directory, don't they?

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK they're the only other options.